# Doesn't have a size known at compile-time

Tags: rust

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<K: Debug, V: Debug> {
    key: K,
    value: V,
}

fn myprint<K: Debug + ?Sized, V: Debug + ?Sized>(node: &Node<K,V>) -> String {
    return format!("{:?}: {:?}", node.key, node.value);
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node{key: "xxx", value: "yyy"};
    myprint(&node);
}
```

compile error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `K` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:22:50
   |
17 | struct Node<K: Debug,V: Debug> {
   |             - required by this bound in `Node`
...
22 | fn myprint<K:Debug+?Sized, V:Debug+?Sized>(node: &Node<K,V>) -> String {
   |            -                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |            |
   |            this type parameter needs to be `std::marker::Sized`
```

But the following code works:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn debug<T: Debug + ?Sized>(t: &T) { // T: Debug + ?Sized
    println!("{:?}", t);
}

fn main() {
    debug("my str"); // T = str, str: Debug + ?Sized ✔️
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All type parameters are implicitly `Sized`.

That means that `struct Node<K: Debug, V: Debug> {...}` is the same as `struct Node<K: Debug + Sized, V: Debug + Sized> {...}`.

In order to allow the `Sized` bound to be removed, a special syntax `?Sized` was added. This means that a type parameter is optionally not `Sized`.

In function `myprint<K:Debug + ?Sized, V:Debug + ?Sized>`, you were allowing K to be **not** `Sized`. Meanwhile, `K` in `Node<K,V>` must be `Sized`. This means that there are type parameters which `myprint` allows but which will cannot be compiled.

The exact same problem also applies to `V`.

---

> how to resolve this problem

Well, the first question is do you need to support `?Sized` as a `K` or `V` in a `Node`? If not, your function doesn't need to support it either.

```
fn myprint<K: Debug, V: Debug>(node: &Node<K,V>) {...}
```

If on the other hand you plan to support `?Sized` `K`/`V`, you need to define your struct correctly:

```
struct Node<K: Debug + ?Sized, V: Debug + ?Sized> {...}
```

> but fn debug<T: Debug+?Sized>(t: &T) can works!

Yep. That is a valid signature. The reason it doesn't work in the other function is the other function says `K`, a type defined as `Debug + ?Sized` needs to be used in `Node<K, V>` which is a `Debug + Sized` (no question mark) context.